# Eclipse keyboard shortcut to an Ant task?

Tags: eclipse, ant, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to run a specific Ant task via the keyboard? I have a rsync to dev task that I run a lot and running to the mouse to double-click is a pain.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you launch regularly the same external launch, you can assign a shortcut to the command:
`"Run Last Launched External Tool"`

(Windows/Preferences: type Keys, then launch, tested with Eclipse Ganymede 3.4.1)

Comment: My version says "Run Last Launched External Tool".

Comment: @thrashr888: You are right: mine too. I just fix this answer to reflect the correct label.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the latest Eclipse. Can anyone confirm that? Is there a newer alternative?

Comment: @thrashr888: on what Eclipse are you not able to define a shortcut for the "Run Last Launched External Tool" command? I still see it on my Eclipse3.6.2.

Answer (score 2):

The following keyboard shortcut is listed in the Eclipse Ganymede help:

Run Ant Build: Alt+Shift+X, Q

Comment: That suppose you have the ant xml file open in your editor right ? By launching the last launched External Tool, you do not have to open it, and you can set all extra variable environments/path you may need to execute said xml ant file...

Comment: You're right. You can toggle this behavior by Windows->Preference->Run/Debug->Launching then change Launch Operation (at the bottom) to "Always launch the previously launched application".